# Use regular expression to extract img tag from HTML in Perl

Tags: html, regex, perl, parsing

I need to extract captcha from url and recognised it with Tesseract.
My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -X
###
$user = 'user'; #Enter your username here
$pass = 'pass'; #Enter your password here
###
#Server settings
$home = "http://perltest.adavice.com";
$url = "$home/c/test.cgi?u=$user&p=$pass";
###Add code here!
#Grab img from HTML code
#if ($html =~ /<img. *?src. *?>/)
#{
#    $img1 = $1;
#}
#else 
#{
#    $img1 = "";
#}
$img2 = grep(/<img. *src=.*>/,$html);
if ($html =~ /\img[^>]* src=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*/)
{
    my $takeImg = $1;
    my @dirs = split('/', $takeImg);
    my $img = $dirs[2];
}
else
{
    print "Image not found\n";
}
###
die "<img> not found\n" if (!$img);
#Download image to server (save as: ocr_me.img)
print "GET '$img' > ocr_me.img\n";
system "GET '$img' > ocr_me.img";
###Add code here!
#Run OCR (using shell command tesseract) on img and save text as ocr_result.txt
system("tesseract ocr_me.img ocr_result");
print "GET '$txt' > ocr_result.txt\n";
system "GET '$txt' > ocr_result.txt";
###
die "ocr_result.txt not found\n" if (!-e "ocr_result.txt");
# check OCR results:
$txt = 'cat ocr_result.txt';
$txt =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]+//sg;
$img =~ s/^.*\///;
print `echo -n "file=$img&text=$txt" | POST "$url"`;
```

As you see I`m trying extract img src tag. This solution did not work for me ($img1) [use shell command tesseract in perl script to print a text output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321827/use-shell-command-tesseract-in-perl-script-to-print-a-text-output). Also I used adopted version of that solution($img2) [How can I extract URL and link text from HTML in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254345/how-can-i-extract-url-and-link-text-from-html-in-perl).

If you need HTMLcode from that page, here is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Perl test</title>
</head>
<body style="font: 18px Arial;">
<nobr>somenumbersimg src="/JJ822RCXHFC23OXONNHR.png" 
somenumbers<img src="/captcha/1533030599.png"/>
somenumbersimg src="/JJ822RCXHFC23OXONNHR.png" </nobr><br/><br/><form method="post" action="?u=user&p=pass">User: <input name="u"/><br/>PW: <input name="p"/><br/><input type="hidden" name="file" value="1533030599.png"/>Text: <input name="text"></br><input type="submit"></form><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

I got error that image not found. My problem is wrong regular expression, as I think.I can not install any modules such as HTTP::Parser or similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the fact that using regular expressions on HTML isn't very reliable, your regular expression in the following code isn't going to work because it's missing a capture group, so `$1` won't be assigned a value.

```
if ($html =~ /<img. *?src. *?>/)
{
    $img = $1;
}
```

If you want to extract parts of text using a regular expression you need to put that part inside brackets. Like for example:

```
$example = "hello world";
$example =~ /(hello) world/;
```

this will set $1 to "hello".

The regular expression itself doesn't make that much sense - where you have ". *?", that'll match any character followed by 0 or more spaces. Is that a typo for ".*?" which would match any number of characters but isn't greedy like ".*", so will stop when it finds a match for the next part of the regex.

This regular expression is possibly closer to what you're looking for. It'll match the first img tag that has a src attribute that starts with "/captcha/" and store the image URL in `$1`

```
$html =~ m%<img[^>]*src="(/captcha/[^"]*)"%s;
```

To break it down how it works. The "m%....%" is just a different way of saying "/.../" that allows you to put slashes in the regex without needing to escape them. "[^>]*" will match zero or more of any character except ">" - so it won't match the end of the tag. And "(/captcha/[^"]*)" is using a capture group to grab anything inside the double quotes that will be the URL. It's also using the "/s" modifier on the end which will treat `$html` as if it is just one long line of text and ignoring any `\n` in it which probably isn't needed, but on the off chance the img tag is split over multiple lines it'll still work.

Comment: The non-greedy version of `.*` is not `.?` but `.*?`. `.?` will match a single character that may not be there.

Comment: @jja My answer is correct, but the *'s are being stripped out by the formatting and used to emphasis bits of it instead :/ I guess I'll need to work out how to fix that

Comment: I thought something was off with the formatting. :) Try wrapping them in "`" so they don't get interpreted as formatting characters

Comment: @jja I've opted for escaping them as that seems to work too

Comment: @Chris Turner you did a very nice explanation, thanks. In output I see that ($img = 'GET /captcha/1533049803.png'). That $img Tesseract don`t recognize. Maybe I need 'GET 1533049803.png' instead of 'GET /captcha/1533049803.png'. Can you give me a regular expression to do this? I am trying to edit your regular expression to achieve this, but did not succeed

Comment: @Oysiyl That is the exact opposite of your problem, you want to specify more of the URL, not less. You want to do (GET 'http ://perltest.adavice.com/captcha/1533049803.png')

Comment: (except without a space after "http" as that is just me trying to stop it from treating it like an actual URL in my comment)

Comment: @Chris Turner yes! I want do this but don`t understand how to add text('http:/perltest.adavice.com') to my $img(/captcha/1533049803.png). I am tried to concatenate $url and $img but this dont work as I expected

Comment: You've got `system "GET '$img' > ocr_me.img";` so make it `system "GET '$home$img' > ocr_me.img";`

Comment: @Chris Turner, yep programm correctly load image. But Tesseract dont recognize anything(GET '' > ocr_result.txt. Captcha text dont specified). In any case, the answer to the question is received. Probably, I will look for more information about Tesseract. If I can not cope with the error, I will ask a new question on site. Thanks for your help